# What is Keras tokenizer.fit_on_texts doing?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tokenize

How to use Keras Tokenizer method `fit_on_texts` ?

How does it differ from `fit_on_sequences` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fit_on_texts` used in conjunction with `texts_to_matrix` produces the one-hot encoding for a text, see https://www.tensorflow.org/text/guide/word_embeddings

[image]

**fit_on_texts**

An example for using `fit_on_texts`

```
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
text='check check fail'
tokenizer = Tokenizer()
tokenizer.fit_on_texts([text])
tokenizer.word_index
```

will produce `{'check': 1, 'fail': 2}`

Note that we use `[text]` as an argument since input must be a list, where each element of the list is considered a token. Input can also be a text generator or a list of list of strings.

Passing a text generator as an input is memory efficient, here an example: (1) defining a text generator returning an iterable collection of texts

```
def text_generator(texts_generator):
    for texts in texts_generator:
        for text in texts:
            yield text
```

(2) passing it as an input to `fit_on_texts`

```
tokenizer.fit_on_text(text_generator)
```

`fit_on_texts` is used before calling `texts_to_matrix` which produces the one-hot encoding for the original set of texts.

**num_words argument**

Passing the `num_words` argument to the tokenizer will specify the number of (most frequent) words we consider in the representation. An example, first `num_words = 1` and we just encode on the most frequent word, `love`

```
sentences = [
    'i love my dog',
    'I, love my cat',
    'You love my dog!'
]

tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words = 1+1)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(sentences)
tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(sentences) # [[1], [1], [1]]
```

Second, `num_words = 100`, we encode on the 100 most frequent words

```
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words = 100+1)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(sentences)
tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(sentences) # [[3, 1, 2, 4], [3, 1, 2, 5], [6, 1, 2, 4]]
```

**fit_on_sequences**

`Fit_on_sequences` works on "sequences" i.e., lists of integer word indices. It is used before calling `sequence_to_matrix`

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
test_seq = [[1,2,3,4,5,6]]
tok = Tokenizer(num_words=10)
tok.fit_on_sequences(test_seq)
tok.sequences_to_matrix(test_seq)
```

Producing

```
array([[0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

Comment: excuse me if i need to use bert tokenizer instead of this way , how can i do that ?